# Opencart translate module

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, translate

Where Im can find file to translate this words ? I already check all checkout.php and  shipping.php

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTnsE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit **Estimate Shipping & Taxes, Country, Region / State, Post Code** text

Go to **catalog/language/english(your language)/checkout/shipping.php** (for oc version 2.0.3.1 and below OC versions)

Go to **catalog/language/english(your language)/total/shipping.php** (for oc version 2.1.x)

You can see following code will be present

```
$_['heading_title']        = 'Estimate Shipping &amp; Taxes';
$_['entry_country']        = 'Country';
$_['entry_zone']           = 'Region / State';
$_['entry_postcode']       = 'Post Code';
```

Comment: thank you! I dont have shipping.php in total folder ;)